# MYSYS2 GCC Static Linking Error: main: linker input file not found: No such file or directory

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, linker, mingw-w64

I'm attempting to statically link a library at a location using MYSYS2 GCC 11.2.0 on Windows.

Here's my makefile: (Edit 1 from M.M and n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m.)

```
#changed .o to .so, ty  "n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m."
libmxn_external_test.so: mxn_external_test.h mxn_external_test.c
    gcc -o libmxn_external_test.so -fpic -shared mxn_external_test.h mxn_external_test.c

#changed .o to .so
libmxn_external_test.a: libmxn_external_test.so
    ar rcs C:\libs\c\libmxn_external_test.a libmxn_external_test.so -v

#changed main to main.c, ty "M.M"
main.o: main.c
    gcc -c main.c

main: main.o
    gcc main.o -LC:\libs\c -lmxn_external_test -o main

#this kinda works but after graduating with a CS degree, and a few hours of make videos, haven't figured out much more yet
quick: main.o libmxn_external_test.so
    gcc -o main main.o libmxn_external_test.o
    
clean:
    rm libmxn_external_test.h.gch libmxn_external_test.so main.o
```

And I receive this error when running "make main":

```
    PS C:\Users\U53R\Desktop\workflow\coding\c\c\projects\PRACTICE\ExternalLibrary> gcc main.o -LC:\libs\c -lmxn_external_test -o main                                                          C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find main.o: No such file or directory
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\libs\c/libmxn_external_test.a(libmxn_external_test.o): in function `atexit':
C:/M/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crtdll.c:205: multiple definition of `atexit'; C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/crt2.o:C:/M/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crtexe.c:418: first defined here
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\libs\c/libmxn_external_test.a(libmxn_external_test.o):cygming-crtbeg:(.text+0x380): multiple definition of `__gcc_register_frame'; C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/crtbegin.o:cygming-crtbeg:(.text+0x0): first defined here
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\libs\c/libmxn_external_test.a(libmxn_external_test.o):cygming-crtbeg:(.text+0x390): multiple definition of `__gcc_deregister_frame'; C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/crtbegin.o:cygming-crtbeg:(.text+0x10): first defined here
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\libs\c/libmxn_external_test.a(libmxn_external_test.o):misc.c:(.rdata+0x5f0): multiple definition of `.refptr.__native_startup_state'; C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/crt2.o:crtexe.c:(.rdata$.refptr.__native_startup_state[.refptr.__native_startup_state]+0x0): first defined here
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\libs\c/libmxn_external_test.a(libmxn_external_test.o):crtdll.c:(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `__mingw_module_is_dll'; C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/crt2.o:C:/M/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crtexe.c:422: first defined here
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\libs\c/libmxn_external_test.a(libmxn_external_test.o):misc.c:(.rdata+0x5c0): multiple definition of `.refptr.__mingw_app_type'; C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/crt2.o:crtexe.c:(.rdata$.refptr.__mingw_app_type[.refptr.__mingw_app_type]+0x0): first defined here
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\libs\c/libmxn_external_test.a(libmxn_external_test.o):misc.c:(.rdata+0x630): multiple definition of `.refptr.__xi_a'; C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/crt2.o:crtexe.c:(.rdata$.refptr.__xi_a[.refptr.__xi_a]+0x0): first defined here
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\libs\c/libmxn_external_test.a(libmxn_external_test.o):misc.c:(.rdata+0x5e0): multiple definition of `.refptr.__native_startup_lock'; C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/crt2.o:crtexe.c:(.rdata$.refptr.__native_startup_lock[.refptr.__native_startup_lock]+0x0): first defined here
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\libs\c/libmxn_external_test.a(libmxn_external_test.o):misc.c:(.rdata+0x5a0): multiple definition of `.refptr.__dyn_tls_init_callback'; C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/crt2.o:crtexe.c:(.rdata$.refptr.__dyn_tls_init_callback[.refptr.__dyn_tls_init_callback]+0x0): first defined here
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\libs\c/libmxn_external_test.a(libmxn_external_test.o):misc.c:(.rdata+0x5b0): multiple definition of `.refptr.__image_base__'; C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/crt2.o:crtexe.c:(.rdata$.refptr.__image_base__[.refptr.__image_base__]+0x0): first defined here
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\libs\c/libmxn_external_test.a(libmxn_external_test.o):misc.c:(.rdata+0x610): multiple definition of `.refptr.__xc_a'; C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/crt2.o:crtexe.c:(.rdata$.refptr.__xc_a[.refptr.__xc_a]+0x0): first defined here
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\libs\c/libmxn_external_test.a(libmxn_external_test.o):misc.c:(.rdata+0x640): multiple definition of `.refptr.__xi_z'; C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/crt2.o:crtexe.c:(.rdata$.refptr.__xi_z[.refptr.__xi_z]+0x0): first defined here
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\libs\c/libmxn_external_test.a(libmxn_external_test.o):misc.c:(.rdata+0x620): multiple definition of `.refptr.__xc_z'; C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/crt2.o:crtexe.c:(.rdata$.refptr.__xc_z[.refptr.__xc_z]+0x0): first defined here
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Two things I noticed from this is:
The "wrong" kind of slash for Windows  C:\libs\c/libmxn_external_test.a

And absurdly long possibly looping filepaths, which may be inherent to using mys64 and mingw.

I DO have my library in C:\libs\c\libmxn_external_test.a

What can I do to get the -L and -l options to work properly on for MYSYS2 gcc?

Comment: You need to use `-c` switch when building `.o` files (that means to compile to object file; without it, it builds an executable)

Comment: also `gcc -c main` should be `gcc -c main.c`

Comment: Why are you compiling .h files? If you want to use precompiled headers (not recommended for small projects), then this is not how you do it. Otherwise just remove mxn_external_test.h from the compilation command.

Comment: You have libmxn_external_test.so in your make rule. You are not building any .so files. That suffix should be .a instead.

Answer (score 0):

try renaming the root folder without spaces between two words. It worked for me. If you have one.

Comment: Please format your answer properly.